# Fix header with variable height on page scroll

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I am trying to learn CSS and building html pages and a bit new in this field.
I wanna build a page with fix header so that when I scroll the page it doesn't disappear however its height will change on scrolling down, so for example if i start scrolling down it shrinks its height or if I start scrolling up with high speed it will show the complete header(scrolling up slowly will not show complete header until i reach to top of page).
I have seen this feature in may website for example http://www.flipkart.com/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to add/remove a class to your header on scrolling using jquery:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $("header").addClass("stickyHeader");
        }
        else {
            $("header").removeClass("stickyHeader");
        }
    });
```

and in css you can add something like this:

```
.stickyHeader{position:fixed;top:0;height:50px}
```

and for your normal header state you can put something like:

```
header{height:100px}
```

Basically, when u add the class on scrolling, you can manipulate via css with it

Comment: thanks for answer but to be frank Thats the part I was aware of, and do not really need the code only the concept. if you visit www.flipkart.com the header can be appear anywhere in page with full height (even if you have scrolled down deeply) for that you need to move your courser upward quickly, and if you keep scrolling up slowly with constant speed the header will not be with its full height.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: fixed; top: 0` if you want element to be fixed always. If you want to change size or smth other when user scrolls to some element on page you need use javascript.